# How to recursively draw simple lines in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, jpanel

SO i have a problem and its so simple that im scared to ask. Im a newbie, pls dont roast me.

What i want is to draw a vertical line: 100 pixel long and 90° angle.
On the top end i want 2 lines with 50 pixels going 45° to the left and right.
SO in the end it would look like an "Y".

I drawed the vertical line but i dont know how to do the rest? Can you help me?

```
for (int q = 0; q < count; q++){

            g.drawLine((int)tempLine.x1, (int)tempLine.y1, (int)tempLine.x2, (int)tempLine.y2);

            tempLine = new Line2D.Double(tempLine.x1+260, tempLine.y1+490, tempLine.x2+260, tempLine.y2+390);
```

Comment: What do you need recursion for ?

Comment: recursion is for drawline

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with recursion all you need to do is draw 3 lines.

So first get it working by drawing a single "Y".

Something like:

```
g.drawLine(0, 0, 25, 25);
g.drawLine(50, 50, 25, 25);
g.drawLine(25, 25, 50, 50);
```

Once this is working then you work on looping code by using variable in the drawline method instead of hard coded values.

Comment: Hm. I need to solve it recursivly. I know i can draw lines like you showed but im not sure if its ok. Maybe i can drae a Y and recall the method everytime at the end?

Comment: Once again this has nothing to do with recursion.

Comment: ok, so i did this. this should be recursive, right?^^    http://pastebin.com/0sYX62yy